# How to cancel automatically pending order with in 7 days in Magento 1.8.1?

Tags: magento-1.8, orders

How can I auto cancel pending orders if they are not processed within 7 days?

Answer (score 4):

Try to set cron job,

In config.xml,

```
    <config>
       <global>
          <module_name>
             <class>Namaspace_Modulename_Model</class>
          </module_name>
       </global>
         <crontab>
                <jobs>
                    <order_cancel_orders>
                        <schedule><cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                        <run><model>modulename/observer::cancelPendingOrders</model></run>
                    </order_cancel_orders>
            </crontab>
        </config>
```

In observer.php

```
         class Namaspace_Modulename_Model_Observer
    {

                public function cancelPendingOrders(){
                            $date = strtotime("-7 day");
                            $result_date  = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $date);
                            $orderCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');

                            $orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('status', 'pending')
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('lteq' =>  $result_date))
                                    ->getSelect()
                                    ->order('main_table.entity_id');

                            $orders ="";
                            foreach($orderCollection->getItems() as $order)
                            {
                              $orderModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
                              $orderModel->load($order['entity_id']);


                              if(!$orderModel->canCancel())
                                continue;

                              $orderModel->cancel();
                              $orderModel->setStatus('canceled_pendings');
                              $orderModel->save();

                            }
            }
  }
```

Comment: Should be `'lt' =>  $result_date`, otherwise all new orders are canceled ;) Also sth like `$result_date = Varien_Date::formatDate("today -7 days", false)` is missing

Comment: Hi thanks for this but which folder craete this file?

Comment: create a new module and place in observer.php

Comment: okay but not working

Comment: check ur module is defined correctly. I updated my answer now

Comment: Ok i create module in local Riot\Cancel how pls upadte

Comment: config.xml in etc and observer.php in Model folder kindly suggest

Comment: update stock automatically auto canceled order?

Comment: Not working  this code